# post.php wordpress load much slow

Tags: wordpress, performance, load

My Wordpress website is going very slow, loading of admin dashboard take much time ,
when I have checked the network tab I have found that post.php load take more than 40s
How can I figure out how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which API calls and SQL Queries effects the load by using plugin like `Query_Monior` (or) you can check which plugins effect the loading speed of your site by checking the URL in plugin like `Code_Profiler`. Depending on what you found you can choose where to fix. If only on `post.php`, check your screen option if pagination is many. Hope it help.